# Docker keeps data but creates a new volume from host folder every "run"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

It seems to be a misunderstood point from me about volumes. I have a docker-compose file with two services : `jobs` which is a Flask api built from a Dockerfile (see below), and `mongo` which is from official MongoDb image.

I have two volumes : `- .:/code` is linked from my host working directory to `/code` folder in the container, and a named volume `mongodata`.

```
version: "3"
services: 
  jobs:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    environment: 
      FLASK_ENV: ${FLASK_ENV}
      FLASK_APP: ${FLASK_APP}
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:3.6.21-xenial"
    restart: "always"
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes: 
      - mongodata:/data/db
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
volumes: 
  mongodata:
```

Dockerfile for `jobs` service :

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=job-checker
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Every time I remove these container and re-run, everything is fine, I still have my data in `mongodata` volume. But when I check the volume list I can see that a new volume is created from `- .:/code` with a long volume name, for example :

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               55c08cd008a1ed1af8345cef01247cbbb29a0fca9385f78859607c2a751a0053
local               abe9fd0c415ccf7bf8c77346f31c146e0c1feeac58b3e0e242488a155f6a3927
local               job-checker_mongodata
```

Here I ran `docker-compose up`, then I removed containers, then ran up again, so I have two volumes from my working folder.

Is this normal that every up create a new volume instead of using the previous one ?

Thanks

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hidden at the end of the [Docker Hub `mongo` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) documentation is a note:

> This image also defines a volume for `/data/configdb`...

The image's Dockerfile in turn contains the [line](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/d9ed7ef5844957fc1f6f69a2c3aa8d5003b18b74/3.6/Dockerfile#L102)

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

When you start the container, you mount your own volume over `/data/db`, but you don't mount anything on the second path.  This causes Docker to create an anonymous volume there, which is the volume you're seeing with only a long hex ID.

It should be safe to remove the extra volumes, especially if you're sure they're not attached to a container and they don't have interesting content.

This behavior has nothing to do with the bind mount in the other container; bind mounts never show up in the `docker volume ls` listing at all.